# How to make Spring to pick a subclass in a property reference?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am trying to use a specialized subclass in a Spring web application for testing.

The application context xml files reference a class in a few bean's properties by the fully qualified class name, like this:

```
<bean id="blahblah" class="x.y.z.Blah">
   <property name="myFooAttribute" ref="x.y.z.Foo"/>
</bean>
```

and I would like to instantiate and use `x.y.z.Bar` instead of `x.y.z.Foo`, everywhere it is used.

In my test I am using a Java based config and importing the XML configuration (legacy stuff that I don't really want to mess too much around) since it feels more natural when I'm going to be patching things and using mocks declared inline.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({
        "classpath:applicationContext-common.xml",
        "classpath:app-servlet.xml"
})
static class TestConfig {
    static class Bar extends Foo {
        //some stuff overridden here
    }

}
```

How can I make all the places that reference to `x.y.z.Foo` use my `Bar` class instead? Preferably without changing the xml files...

Comment: Just add a bean of type `Bar` and none of type `Foo`?

Comment: The `Foo` bean is not defined anywhere that I am aware of, I think it is just making a singleton bean since it has a default constructor without arguments...

Comment: but maybe I'm wrong, I'm not very familiar with this Spring stuff... in either case, I don't want to alter the original configuration for my testing purposes, I'd like to just override the necessary bits

Comment: Is this for a functional (subsystem) test of a test of the entire application stack from the ground up?

Comment: the entire application

Comment: I've updated the class names, I messed with which ones were Foos and Bars... u^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a bean named as the class that you are trying to override works. It can be achieved in the Java style configuration using the `Bean` annotation.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({
        "classpath:applicationContext-common.xml",
        "classpath:app-servlet.xml"
})
static class TestConfig {
    static class Bar extends Foo {
        //some stuff overridden here
    }
    private Bar myTestBar = new Bar();
    @Bean(name="x.y.z.Foo")
    public Foo getFoo() {
       return myTestBar;
    }
}
```